# Tracking down a Windows 7 Appcrash

Tags: windows-7, crash

An application named wblocks4.exe causes an Appcrash on one Windows 7 laptop (\WER\ReportArchive crash report appended), but works on another Windows 7 laptop. I'm trying to figure out what goes wrong with the first system.

After researching the Appcrash topic I tried a number of things (always as administrator):

- Running sfc /scannow in command window
- Disabling DEP for wblocks4.exe
- Replacing kernelbase.dll (listed as fault module in report below)
- Creating a new account and reinstalling
- Reinstalling the program in Safe Mode

Nothing worked. What else can I try?

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=132829312087198094
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=786116cb-5381-11ec-be5c-0cd2928b3223
WOW64=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=wblocks4.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=4.0.0.29600
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=5589c9a4
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=6.1.7601.17514
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=4ce7bafa
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=e053534f
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=0000b727
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Writer's Blocks 4\wblocks4.exe
UI[3]=Writer's Blocks 4 has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Writer's Blocks 4\wblocks4.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc\MSVCR80.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\syswow64\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsec.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\syswow64\imagehlp.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\system32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\GPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\cryptnet.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\system32\SensApi.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\system32\Cabinet.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\system32\DEVRTL.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\syswow64\psapi.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_72d18a4386696c80\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Writer's Blocks 4\Infragistics2.Win.v9.1.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Writer's Blocks 4\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v9.1.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Writer's Blocks 4\Infragistics2.Shared.v9.1.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Writer's Blocks 4\IDEALSoftware.VpeProfessional.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
FriendlyEventName=APPCRASH
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Writer's Blocks 4
AppPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Writer's Blocks 4\wblocks4.exe
ReportDescription=Stopped working
```

Answer (score 1):

This program is ancient, there won't be any fix for it.

If it has gone bad for some reason,
you may try to uninstall and reinstall it.
That is the most that can be done.

Comment: That same program installs and runs fine on another Windows 7 laptop. So it's a problem with the system, not the program.

Comment: I suggest reinstalling it on the system where it's already installed, to refresh the installation. This will tell whether the problem is or is not with the program, meaning that something went wrong with the program on this computer.

Comment: To be clear, the program is installed on both Windows 7 machines. On my backup laptop it runs, which tells me the program is okay (and I don't want to incur the risk of changing that by reinstalling it). On my main laptop the installed program doesn't run, which suggests that laptop has something that causes the appcrash. That's what I was hoping to track down here, after trying many things, but the admin deems the question not clear enough, so yours is the only response I'll get, which I appreciate.

Comment: Thanks. If you have been willing to try and get us more information, perhaps the moderator wouldn't have closed this post.

Comment: I did add information and refocused the question. No go. BUT, I have the answer: all I had to do was install the Windows updates. Now the program runs. Since the problem is solved I thought I'd delete the question but "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it"...